# Angular2 - Download XLS received from RestService

Tags: java, excel, angular, apache-poi

I want to make a WS to generate a Excel (xls, xlsx) file with apachePOI. I made something like the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void exportXlsx(HttpServletResponse response) {

    // getting datas for file
    try {

        Workbook wb = //creating the file
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + entity.getType() + ".xls");
        wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
}
```

This service it's working, and returning a correct file if i'm calling the service.  I need to add for this service a GUI using Angular2. 
Calling this service like:

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post("URL", options);
```

I'm receiving some errors like : 406 (Not Acceptable).
I tried all possible solutions what I found on forums, no success.

Answer (score 1):

Your Accept header suggests that the response has the xslx file format (`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`) but the file you send has extension `.xls`.

Either change the file's extension to `.xlsx` or use mime type `application/vnd.ms-excel`